# onkeypress for yii textfield

Tags: javascript, php, yii, textfield

i got this line of code showing a textfield

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'READING_YEAR'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'READING_YEAR',array('size'=>4,'maxlength'=>4)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'READING_YEAR'); ?>
</div>
```

and i want to be able to enter only numbers in the textfield using a javascript

```
<script>
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
}
</script>
```

how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just add this in your Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('your-element').onkeypress = function(evt){
    return isNumberKey(evt);
}
```

Comment: ok sorry, will delete later, but all those links are using html text inputs, im using php textfields

Comment: i dont think i understand, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @cipher1285 I assume you got your `isNumberKey(evt)` function from [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/39/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-allow-only-numbers-to-be-entered-in-a-textbox), since the code is identical. In their example, their `input` element has an `onkeypress` attribute equal to `return isNumberKey(event)`. My example yields the same outcome but instead, you do not need to add the `onkeypress` attribute to your textbox, which you cannot do since you are using PHP textfields.

Comment: ok so i added your code in my javascript, but how will i call my javascript from my textfields? sorry im still new in yii and php.

Comment: @cipher1285 `document.getElementById('your-element').onkeypress = function(evt){ return isNumberKey(evt); }` means that whenever a keyboard key has been pressed and the user is entering text into the textbox, it will run the function. So all you have to do is put that in your Javascript and add the Javascript to your page and it should work automatically.

Comment: @cipher1285 this is called a _Javascript Event_. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) gives a pretty good explanation of what they are and how they work.